# Creating Custom Forms in the Django Admin Interface with Parler

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-parler

I have a django 1.8 instance (and python 2) and I am using django-parler for translation. I want to customize the admin interface (I want to use django-autocomplete-light, but that's not relevant). But customizing the admin interface with parler seems a bit more tricky then I thought. Here is a reduced example.

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from parler.models import TranslatableModel, TranslatedFields


class Fruits(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        fname=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fname
```

### forms.py

```
from dal import autocomplete
from django import forms

from .models import Fruits

class FruitsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Fruits
        fields = (
            'fruits',
        )
```

### admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from parler.admin import TranslatableAdmin

from .forms import FruitsForm
from .models import Fruits


class FruitsAdmin(TranslatableAdmin):
    form = FruitsForm
    model = Fruits


admin.site.register(Fruits, FruitsAdmin)
```

### The Problem

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (fruits) specified for Fruits`

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT #1:**

After a bit of searching around, I believe that you have to make your form inherit from `parler.formsTranslatableModelForm` in order to work as expected.

Change your `FruitsForm` to match the following:

```
from dal import autocomplete
from django import forms
from parler.forms import TranslatableModelForm

from .models import Fruits

class FruitsForm(TranslatableModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Fruits
        fields = (
            'fname',
        )
```

In case of `fname` giving you the same issue, try to set `fields='__all__'`

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this does not work:

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (translations) specified for Fruits`

Comment: I edited my answer, have a look (change `translations` to `fname`)

Comment: Even that does not work :( `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (fname) specified for Fruits`

Comment: I found some info, take a look in the reedited answer

Comment: Good to know mate! Happy coding :)